# How do I play quests with a friend?

Tags: tera

A friend and I started playing TERA and have finished the section on Stepstone Isle and are now in Velika. We are in a party together and have added each other to our friends lists. So far any main story quests we've done have been separate, so we were just doing them at the same time.

After some Googling, I found that we can share quests and complete objectives together, but everywhere I look has something different to say on how to do this.

How can we complete quests together? If we can only do certain quests together, how do I tell which those are?

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with asking questions here, you'll probably get faster and better answers on your region publisher's forum. [EnMasse](https://forums.enmasse.com/tera/) for North America, [Gameforge](http://board.tera.gameforge.com/) for Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting island is a bit different from regular leveling so don't mind it.

Regular quests (yellow exclamation mark) and most story quests (red) can be done in a party. If you are in the same party (not a raid!) and sufficiently close to each other (maximum 30m iirc), progress (kills, gathering, using objects) will count for both of you.

Some specific quests are solo instances, meaning you must enter alone, usually through a portal. Obviously you cannot do these together. Vanguard requests, (a second quest system you'll unlock soon) can be done in a party too, though the progress is "round-robin" for the BAM ones, meaning you need to do (# of players in party) x (quest requirement).

Some specific gathering quests require crafting materials (such as plants, ore, energy). They don't count as shared because the items are actual items, and not just a quest counter.

Dungeons are no different. As long as you both have the quest, you can do it together.